# In a MYSQL table of word definitions, within sql add 3 columns/fields of definitions taken randomly from other rows

Tags: mysql, select, random, nested

I have a MYSQL table called aa_ngl_defs of the following form:

| id | Word | POS | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | the | article | used to point to something already mentioned |
| 2 | be | verb | used to show the identity of a thing |
| 3 | and | conj | used to join words or groups of words |
| 4 | of | prep | belonging to or connected with something |
| 5 | to | prep | used to indicate place or direction |
| 6 | a | article | one particular thing or one of a class of things |
| 7 | in | prep | used to indicate being inside of or surrounded by something else |
| 8 | have | verb | to own, possess, or hold something |
| 9 | it | pronoun | a thing that has been previously mentioned |
| 10 | you | pronoun | used to refer to the person the speaker is addressing |
| 11 | he | pronoun | used to refer to a male person that is the subject |
| 12 | for | prep | indicating the purpose or need of something |
| 13 | they | pronoun | used to refer to two or more people, animals, or things |
| 14 | not | adverb | used to make an expression negative |
| 15 | that | adj | used to identify a specific person, thing, fact or idea |
| 16 | we | pronoun | used to refer to the speaker and another person as the subject |
| 17 | on | prep | touching and being supported or physically in contact by something |

The table has unique contiguous integers in the id column.

I want to create a new table by adding 3 columns of definitions taken randomly from other rows within this table.  This would allow me to create quizzes with 3 distractors.  I need reasonable performance speed but not necessarily high speed, as the table has 3,500 rows but I only need to generate a new quiz once-a-week.

So that it looks like this:

```
id  Word    POS Correct_Definition   Distractor1    Distractor2   Distractor3
```

The online quiz generators Quizlet, Kahoot and Blooket are able to take a simple list like this and produce quizzes with 3 distractors.  That's what I'm trying to emulate.

The following works OK for adding 1 extra distractor definition:

```
    SELECT t1.id, t1.Word, t1.Definition, t2.Definition
    FROM aa_ngl_defs AS t1
    LEFT JOIN aa_ngl_defs AS t2 
      ON t1.id <> t2.id -- Ensure we don't join the row with itself
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 3;
```

But I don't know how to add two more distractor definitions, and also my query took 17s which I suspect will multiply exponentially if I try to add more columns.

I tried to incorporate the following to improve performance

```
    SELECT *
      FROM aa_ngl_defs AS r1 JOIN
        (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM aa_ngl_defs)) AS id
        )
            AS r2
     WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
    ORDER BY r1.id ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

... and this works very fast to select one row at random, but I am completely lost as to how incorporate this to add the three distractors.  I think I need nested select statements or perhaps variables.

Obviously, since each row will have 3 distractors there will be some repeats of distractors across rows, but I can't have repeated distractors within any single row.  Randomness only needs to be reasonably random, not strictly so.

Comment: I fixed the layout of you input data.  In this case it might even be better to have posted a DBFIDDLE, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/2d9zO9Us  (It saves a lot of time for someone who tries to answer your question )

Comment: Do you need to _first_ pick 17 random rows rows, _then_ shuffle?  Or do you need to pick   Or do you need to do the shuffling, _then_ pick 17?  I presume it is the former.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. You can move the random rows logic into a lateral join and then apply a *row_number*, followed by conditional aggregation to pivot into your required columns:

```
select id, word, pos, Definition Correct_Definition,
  max(case when cn = 1 then rdef end) Distractor1,
  max(case when cn = 2 then rdef end) Distractor2,
  max(case when cn = 3 then rdef end) Distractor3
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by t.id) cn
  from t
  join lateral (
      select definition rdef
      from t t2
      where t2.id != t.id
      order by rand()
      limit 3
  )r
)t
group by id, word, pos, definition;
```

See this [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_8y9zWGR)

Comment: Thank you :) testing this, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temp table called `distractors`.  Fill it with `definition` and order by `RAND()`.  This is the slowest step, and it won't be very slow.  (Include an index on `distractor` to help step 3.)
2. Create the `quiz` table (without the distractors, *yet*) with the 17 random questions for today.  This may involve `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 17`.  Be sure to include ids 1..17, as indicated in your example.
3. Delete from `distractors` the 17 questions for today.  (Multi-table `DELETE`)  (This avoids any distractor matching any question in the result)
4. `ALTER TABLE distractors ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;`  (This creates the numbers to use in the next step.)
5. Add the first random 17 questions from `distractors` to `quiz.distractor1`.  Add the next 17 questions to  `distractor2`; etc.  Use something like this to do this step.  (This prevents any dup disractors.)

   ```
   UPDATE   quiz
       JOIN distractors
           ON distractors.id = quiz.id + 0;
       SET quiz.distractor1 = distractors.definition
   UPDATE   quiz
       JOIN distractors
           ON distractors.id = quiz.id + 17;
       SET quiz.distractor2 = distractors.definition
   UPDATE   quiz
       JOIN distractors
           ON distractors.id = quiz.id + 34;
       SET quiz.distractor3 = distractors.definition
   ```

(The 3 `UPDATEs` differ in only two places.)

Tip:  Use `VARCHAR(191)`, not `TEXT` -- so that indexing will work.  (The probably does not have any long definitions.)